# Can I pass SQL queries and their subqueries without creating separate tables?

Tags: sql, select, nested, subquery

Given the following code, is it possible to pass a query and its subqueries to a later calculation (a pivot table with some arithmetic) without creating a table?

The tables `LOGS` and `USERS` only share the field `USERNAME`.

```
    (SELECT z.* FROM (SELECT
            L.DATE,
            UPPER(L.USERNAME) AS USERNAME,
            L.BUSINESS,
            (SELECT name FROM UID where UID_code= L.transfer) AS newname,
            L.REASON
            FROM LOGS L
            WHERE L.APPLICATION = 'A'
            AND L.BUSINESS IN ('X','Y','Z')
            AND L.DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('1/1/2019 00:00:01', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE('2/1/2019    23:59:59','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
        AND UPPER(L.USERNAME) IN (SELECT UPPER(U.USERNAME) FROM USERS U WHERE TEAM='DATA'))z
        WHERE z.REASON ='N/A')
    ) AS EDITS; /*Alias needed to pass this query?*/
```

Or would I need to start with

```
CREATE TABLE EDITS_ONLY
SELECT DATE, USERNAME, BUSINESS
FROM
```

Or

```
SELECT DATE,USERNAME,BUSINESS
INTO EDITS_ONLY
FROM
```

Trying to modify anything other than my nested SELECT queries results in an improperly ended SQL statement error. (ORA-00933) There are 3 blocks of code like this that need to be filtered and compared against one another before the desired output. Can I simply assign the outer query a name? What are my alternatives? Thanks.

Comment: That's what CTEs (Common Table Expressions) were designed for.

Comment: You might also look into views if you want to avoid code duplication.

Comment: @shawnt00 Thanks. That seems to be the way forward.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get the meaning of your existing query, but you can "save" subqueries as CTEs (Common Table Expressions) and name them. In later queries you can reference them as if they were typical tables. For example:

```
with
z (username) as ( -- CTE named "z"
  SELECT UPPER(U.USERNAME) FROM USERS U WHERE TEAM = 'DATA'
),
edits (dt, username, business, newname, reason) as ( -- CTE named "edits"
   SELECT
     L.DATE,
     UPPER(L.USERNAME),
     L.BUSINESS,
     (SELECT name FROM UID where UID_code = L.transfer),
     L.REASON
     FROM LOGS L
     WHERE L.APPLICATION = 'A'
       AND L.BUSINESS IN ('X','Y','Z')
       AND L.DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('1/1/2019 00:00:01', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
                      AND TO_DATE('2/1/2019    23:59:59','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
       AND UPPER(L.USERNAME) IN (SELECT * from z WHERE REASON = 'N/A')
)
select * from edits
```

This may give you a starting point with your query. Yours is malformed so I couldn't understand it well.